# How to limit the range of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mouseevent

I am building a slider component in React JS, and it's working, however I am facing a bug which I believe to be a conflict between `onMouseDown` and `onMouseLeave` events.

I have the div `range-container`, which receives the events, inside it I have another div and within this last one I have two spans, they are the thumbs of my slider.

This is what is happening:

[image]

As seen in this gif the thumbs don't respect the limits of the line as they should. The data on the left are the variable `move`, responsable to determine whether the `X` can be changed or not and the position of the mouse.

This is how it should work:

`onMouseDown` sets `move` to `true` and allows the thumb to move;

`onMouseUp` sets `move` as `false` and blocks the movements;

`onMouseMove` changes the value of `value` and makes the thumb moves;

`onMouseLeave` sets `move` to `false` and also blocks the movements.

I realize that `onMouseLeave` is only triggered when the cursor leaves the element and its children, because of that I can't just leave the div, I need to leave the thumb as well, but I don't know how to limit it by the limits of the line.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

import './Filter.css'

const Filter = props => {

    let [value, setValue] =  React.useState(190)
    let [move, setMove] =  React.useState(false)

    const handleChange = e => {
        var x = e.clientX;
        if (move === true) {
            setValue(x)
        }
        
    };
    
    const moveOn = e => {
        var x = e.clientX;
        setValue(x)
        setMove(true)
    }
    
    const moveOff = () => {
        setMove(false)
    }
    

    let moveText = 'false'
    move === true ? moveText = 'true' : moveText = 'false'

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>{moveText}</div>
            <div>{value}</div>
            <div className="filter-container d-flex justify-content-between">
                    
                    <div className="range-container"
                        onMouseMove={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                        onMouseDown={(e) => moveOn(e)}
                        onMouseUp={() => moveOff()}
                        onMouseLeave={() => moveOff()}
                    >
                        <div className="range" 
                            
                        >
                            <span className="rounded-circle" 
                                style={{
                                    width:'15px', 
                                    height: '15px', 
                                    backgroundColor: 'red', 
                                    marginTop: '-6px',
                                    left: value - 7 + 'px'
                                }}
                                ></span>
                            <span className="rounded-circle" 
                                style={{
                                    width:'10px', 
                                    height: '10px', 
                                    backgroundColor: 'black', 
                                    marginTop: '-4px', 
                                    marginLeft: '195px'
                                }}
                                
                                ></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Filter
```

CSS:

```
.range-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.range {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.range span {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't rely on the events to reach what I aimed, so I had to change a little the perspective.

What I did was to store the initial position of the thumb in a variable and only change `value` if it is higher than the initial value, otherwise `value` receives the value of `off_x`.

```
const off_x = 190 // initial position
let [value, setValue] =  React.useState(off_x)
let [move, setMove] =  React.useState(false)


const handleChange = e => {
    var x = e.clientX;
    if (move === true) {
        value > off_x ? setValue(x) : setValue(off_x)
    }
    
}
```

Now it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I have more success when using mouseout instead of mouseleave. The mouseleave function never get called then the click is held. You can check this code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-edison-63s0h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I've tried with `mouseOut`, it was my first idea, however mouseOut fires when the cursor leaves any children components. The problem is that if the mouse is moved faster than the thumb it'll leave it, triggers the mouseOut event and stop the process, what can't happen in my case. The process must stop only if mouseOn is triggered or if the cursor is out of the line area.